# I want to take characters from a string and populate those characters in 2 different sets in python?

Tags: python, string

1. `comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}"`
2. I want the above string to be distributed to 2 different sets. `S0_list = [{1},{2},{3}] and S1_list = {1,2},{2,3}.`
3. The code basically has to run through each character in my string above(comp) and put single elements(`{1},{2}`) in S0 and double elements (`{1,2},{2,3}`) in S1.
4. This is the code I have so far.

   ```
   S0_list = []
   S1_list = []
   new_set = set()
   comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}"
   pos = 0
   S0_list = S1_list = [0]

   while pos < len(comp):
       if comp[pos] == '{':
          pos = pos + 1
          count = 1


   while comp[pos] != '}':
       pos = pos + 1
       if comp[pos] == ',':
           count = count + 1
       if count == 1:
           S0_list.append(new_set)

       elif count == 2:
           S1_list.append(new_set)
   ```

   pos = pos + 1

Can someone please help without marking me down for bad format of questions.

Comment: What is your question?  What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thank you for your time. I have a string which is named as comp. I want to take elements of those and spread them into two different sets. Just as I have showed. However, I dont know how to ask the code, for an example to take {1} and {1,2} into set S0 and S1 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, find the groups inside `{}`, split them by comma and check its length

```
import re
S0_list = []
S1_list = []
comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}"

for proto_set in re.findall('{([\d,?]+)}', comp):
    set_elements = set(proto_set.split(","))
    if len(set_elements)  > 1: 
        S1_list.append(set_elements)
    else:
        S0_list.append(set_elements)
```

Comment: Sir, I have been trying to understand this code. I am having trouble understanding the use of proto_set as well the meaning of this  (''{([\d,?]+)}'). Is it possible for you to teach me?. As far as my research goes, \d is for the matching of a single digit and + sign is for all positive and negative numbers. I dont understand the '?' sign next to it and how to comment that entire line if I am to teach someone.

Comment: Regex: I'm searching for a match that would be: a number (here's the '\d') and a comma can appear zero or more times(here's the '?') between keys '{}'. The whole match can appear one or more time (here's the '+'). These regex will match with '[0-9],[0-9]' substrings between keys. Then I've splitted that string by comma, and convert that array in a set. Depends on its length, I've appended in one result list or in another

Answer (score 1):

Note that the syntax in `comp` is basically valid Python already, so we can `eval()` it (assuming that it is not untrusted input from a user!):

```
>>> comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}"

>>> values = eval('(' + comp + ')')
>>> values
(set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([1, 2]), set([2, 3]))

>>> S0_list = [x for x in values if len(x) == 1]
>>> S1_list = [x for x in values if len(x) == 2]
>>> S0_list
[set([1]), set([2]), set([3])]
>>> S1_list
[set([1, 2]), set([2, 3])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your input was very valuable. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have been trying to understand 2nd line of the code you provided. Can you tell me what does + comp + do please? If you can tell me that will be so great. Thanks again. I really want to understand the syntax. I have been trying to look it up but mostly the internet gives examples which are general evaluations.

Comment: It adds `(` and `)` around `comp` which is the syntax in Python to create a `tuple`.  Like how `[1,2,3]` makes a list, `(1,2,3)` makes a tuple.  You could use either in this case; I used tuple because it may be marginally more efficient and you don't need to modify it (a list can be modified, tuples cannot).

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import sys

comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}"
set_size1 = set()
set_size2 = set()

[getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "set_size{}".format(s.count(",") + 1)).add(s)
 for s in [v if idx == 0 else "{" + v for idx, v in enumerate(comp.split(",{"))]]

print set_size1, set_size2
```

**Output:**

```
set(['{3}', '{1}', '{2}']) set(['{1,2}', '{2,3}'])
```

**A little explanation** We are using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to iterate over the string and to [split](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) it, Then I'm counting the number of `,` in the string and with that number we can get the right object of sets (by its name) to update using [getattar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Here you can more set sizes to get different elements for example lets add a **3 digit** option:

```
import sys

comp = "{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{2,3,4}"
set_size1 = set()
set_size2 = set()
set_size3 = set()

[getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "set_size{}".format(s.count(",") + 1)).add(s)
 for s in [v if idx == 0 else "{" + v for idx, v in enumerate(comp.split(",{"))]]

print set_size1, set_size2, set_size3
```

**Output:**

```
set(['{3}', '{1}', '{2}']) set(['{1,2}', '{2,3}']) set(['{2,3,4}'])
```

Comment: I am going to go through this carefully and try to understand the syntax and logic. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: NP, It's a bit much if your a beginner but I've tried to attach the needed links to help you learn, If you need any explanation feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes @Kobi K. I started coding in the beginning of July. So currently I am a beginner. 2-3 hours a day type coder. I will definitely look into this more also because it looks very elegant as well. I will ask yo for sure.